# LDAP Find groups for a Active Directory User in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I am trying to validate user with LDAP and return all the groups (to which) user belong:

I am able to validate but not able to get all the groups.

Following code working on local machine but return errors on when deployed on server.

```
public bool Authenticate1(string userName, string password, ref List<string> List)
        {
            const int ERROR_LOGIN_FAILURE = -2147023570;
            DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE", userName, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            using (root)
            {
                try
                {
                        Object temp = root.NativeObject;
                        string defaultNamingContext = "";
                        defaultNamingContext = root.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
                        DirectoryEntry default1 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + defaultNamingContext, userName, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                        DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(default1.Path);
                        dSearch.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userName + ")";
                        dynamic a = dSearch.FindOne();
                        **DirectoryEntry obUser = new DirectoryEntry(a.Path);**
                        object obGroups = obUser.Invoke("Groups");
                        foreach (object ob in (IEnumerable)obGroups)
                        {
                            // Create object for each group.
                            DirectoryEntry obGpEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ob);
                            dynamic vGroup = obGpEntry.Name;
                            vGroup = vGroup.Substring(vGroup.IndexOf("=") + 1, vGroup.Length - vGroup.IndexOf("=") - 1);
                            List.Add(vGroup);
                        }
                    return true;
                }
                catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
                {
                    List.Add(ex.Message);
                    List.Add(ex.ToString());
                    if (ex.ErrorCode != ERROR_LOGIN_FAILURE)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

In this code following line throw error

```
DirectoryEntry obUser = new DirectoryEntry(a.Path);
```

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*
On server pool is running under ApplicationPoolIdentity. As per company policy it should run under that.

Not sure what I am missing here on server?

Cheers
Harry!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName );

    if(user != null)
    {
       // get the user's groups
       PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

       foreach(GroupPrincipal gp in groups.OfType<GroupPrincipal>)
       {
          // do something with the group
       }
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Yes, I tried this was as well and it worked locally and on server it did not worked with AppPool configured with "ApplicationPoolIdentity". But it worked with configuring AppPool with Custom account by setting Domain\User. which can't be done in our organization because  it need new Active Directory account.